# UrlHelper.Action() skipping over empty properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, urlhelper

The model below used in two ways:

```
public class SimpleModel
{
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    // Some other properties

    public SimpleModel()
    {
         Date = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

When model is used in the form, generated URL have empty parameter Date (`/Controller/Action?Date=&SomeOtherParams=123`) and `Date` property in model is `null` (after submitting form with empty date).

```
...

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date)

...
```

Also this model used as third parameter in `UrlHelper.Action()`:

```
@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", Model) // Model is SimpleModel
```

In this case if `Date` is null, generated URL does not contains parameter Date (`/Controller/Action?SomeOtherParams=123`). And if I following this URL, property `Date` is `DateTime.Now`, not null as expected.

How to force passing empty properties to URL?

**UPD. Action code**

```
public ActionResult MyAction( SimpleModel model = null )
{
     if ( model.Date == null )
     {
        // show all
     }
     else
     {
        // show by date
     }
}
```

Actually, instead of `TextBoxFor` used `DropDownListFor`.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.Date, Model.Dates)
```

User can choose Date from DropDown or live it empty if he want to see all entities.

If user submiting form with empty Date, he following URL `/Controller/Action?Date=` and getting all entities (Date property was initialized with default value in constructor and then overriten with null).

If user following by generated url via `@Url.Action` from other page (not submitting form), he getting only todays entities, because URL not contains Date parameter (`/Controller/Action`). In this case Date property initializing in constructor and this is all.

Problem is `model` in `MyAction` never equals null and I cant recognize when user selects empty Date and when he just visit page without parameters.

Comment: I found very dirty solution: `@Url.Action( "Action", "Controller", Model )&amp;Date=` will generate `/Controller/Action?SomeOtherParams=123&Date=`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `Date` to be null, then remove the line that assigns DateTime.Now in the empty constructor.

```
public SimpleModel()
{
   //This line is assigning the value to Date whenever a new SimpleModel() is created. Comment it out.
   //  Date = DateTime.Now;  

}
```

Comment: I cant do this, it will change `SimpleModel` behaviour.

Comment: upload the code in the action method that handles the url: `/Controller/Action?SomeOtherParams=123`

Comment: I explained what I need in the post. See UPD.

Answer (score 1):

> And if I following this URL, property Date is DateTime.Now, not null as expected.

The problem is that the MVC engine is trying to construct a `Model` object based on the constructor you defined, which sets the `Date` property to `DateTime.Now`. It's advised that you do not define a constructor with empty parameters as it will be used by the MVC engine to create the model on `POST`. As it stands, this is expected behavior.

If you need the functionality, then define another constructor:

```
public SimpleModel() // Left for MVC
{
}

public SimpleModel(DateTime date) // Use as: new SimpleModel(DateTime.Now) in your action 
{
     Date = date;
}
```

Comment: I describe it incorrectly, yes, this is expected behavior. And I using this expected behavior to set `Date` with default value in constructor. Problem is I cant recognize when user selects empty Date and when he just visit page without parameters (is this case `Date` must have default value, not null).

Comment: So, you want `Date` to be `null` so you can check whether is was selected or not, right? In this case, this will never happen since you are always setting `Date` to `DateTime.Now` in your constructor. Now, is the problem is passing the `Model` through the `Url.Action` method, you gonna run into problems since parsing the model. You'll better off passing a date by itself to the `Action`.